# Navbar dropdown not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have the code below, but the dropdown is not working, any ideas?
Do I need to add "$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();" to my javascript file?

```
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top
  .navbar-inner
    .container
      %button.btn.btn-navbar{"data-target" => ".nav-collapse", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :type => "button"}
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar
      = link_to I18n.t(:site_title), root_url, :class => "brand"
      .nav-collapse
        %ul.nav
          %li= link_to I18n.t(:nav_thelist)
          %li= link_to I18n.t(:nav_themap)
          %li= link_to I18n.t(:nav_the92)
          %li.dropdown
            %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", "data-target" => "#", :href => "#"}
              = I18n.t(:nav_admin)
              %b.caret
            %ul.dropdown-menu
              %li= link_to I18n.t(:nav_leagues), leagues_url
              %li= link_to I18n.t(:nav_clubs), clubs_url
              %li= link_to I18n.t(:nav_visits), visits_url
```

Comment: your haml seems ok. do you have the requisite bootstrap-dropdown.js included on the page?

Comment: thanks, that worked. Can you add it as an answer, then I can give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdowns in Twitter-Bootstrap require not only the appropriate attributes and CSS, but also the appropriate javascript plugins. Check here to make sure you have the right javascript plugins installed for dropdowns:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using twitter-bootstrap-rails gem
it names the require path incorrectly in application.js
Change it to
//= require bootstrap